# asp LinkButton _doPostBack

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have the following menu:

```
<header class="logged-in clearfix" runat="server" id="hdrLoggedIn" visible="false">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li runat="server" ID="liLoggedIn"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLoggedIn" OnClick="btnLoggedIn_Click" CausesValidation="false" /></li>
                <li runat="server" ID="liChangePwd"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnChangePwd" Text="Change Password" OnClick="btnChangePwd_Click" CausesValidation="false" /></li>
                <li runat="server" ID="liIdUpload"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnIdUpload" Text="ID Upload" OnClick="lnkIdUpload_Click" CausesValidation="false" /></li>    
                <li runat="server" ID="liAdmin"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnAdmin" Text="Admin" OnClick="btnAdmin_Click" CausesValidation="false" /></li>     
                <li runat="server" ID="liLogout"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLogout" Text="Logout" OnClick="btnLogout_Click" CausesValidation="false" /></li>
                <li runat="server" ID="liUnsub"><a href="unsubscribe.aspx">Unsubscribe User</a></li>
                <li runat="server" ID="liPerfMon"><a href="adminmonitor.aspx">Performance Monitor</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And this in developer tools:

[image]

Which leads me to believe that asp.net is adding in the `_doPostBack` function (unless I am missing something as I did not make this application).

This is a global header menu declared in the master page.

My problem is that, the menu works fine on all the pages except one particular page.

I have tried adding a `Response.Write` to the `onClick` method, but this does not get triggered, which leads me to believe that the `onClick` is not getting fired.

If it is not getting fired, it seems the most obvious possibility is that the `_doPostBack` is somehow failing and preventing the `onClick` method from firing?

If this is the case, or sounds sensible to anyone, why is this happening, and what can I do to resolve it.

Possibly something in the page it is not working or is conflicting with the `_doPostBack` ? Or something else?

Any ideas?

Comment: does `btnChangePwd_Click` a javascript function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of \_\_doPostBack function, and when is it used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376055/what-is-the-meaning-of-dopostback-function-and-when-is-it-used)

Comment: Check the browser console and see if any error is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `OnClick` property, you assign event handler for the `Click` event of the target control. So in your example I assume that you have implemented server method `btnChangePwd_Click` in your code behind. To trigger this method, the rendered page must be sent to the server using POST method - you have form on your page. Because `asp:LinkButton` is rendered in the resulting HTML as `a` element, and this element does not trigger posting of the form, ASP.NET renders special helping method `__doPostBack` which is a simple javascript function, which takes its input argument (the input argument is the id of the element which is triggering the postback) set this argument as a value for the hidden field in the form, and then it sends the form. On the server side, according to the value which was supplied as in input argument, .NET knows which server function should be called.

So if your menu does not work only on one particular page, check if you do not have some javascript error on the page, or some mismatched html code rendered, which can destroy all this logic.