# How to insert one column in some table from one combobox on web form in asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, combobox

everybody.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I have a table Employees with three columns id int primary key, first_name varchar not null, last_name varchar not null.

Also, I have table Product which consist of id_Product primary key, name varchar not null, id_emp int not null which is foreign key.

On web form, I have one combobox that present id_emp column which contain all first_name and last_name from table Employees. When I select certain value from combobox I have to insert in table Product. I don't have any idea how to put first_name and last_name from table Employees in combobox.

Note: When you insert data first_name and last_name from combobox, you should get the same value in id_emp such as value in id column in table Employees.

I hope so that I don't confuse you. I tried to present my problem on simple way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please edit your question to include some code that you've already written:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: On click on combo box sent postback and in postback send the id and what other information you want.. based on employee id insert things you want in product table.

Comment: I don't understand how to insert values from two columns in combo box.

Comment: When user clicks on combo box get the value of selected combo box using jquery and pass to ajax ...

Comment: I don't know how to use jquery and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

1) How to populate Combo box 
[How to populate c# windows forms combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423911/how-to-populate-c-sharp-windows-forms-combobox?rq=1)

2) How to do postback in dropdown 
https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-use-dropdownlist-autopostback.html

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroupNameFilter" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLeadgroupName_SelectedIndexChange">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

3) Another way around is to use javascript or jquery to get selected value and append values to postback. 
[What is the meaning of __doPostBack function, and when is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376055/what-is-the-meaning-of-dopostback-function-and-when-is-it-used)

```
function getSelectedvalue(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("<%= btn.ClientID %>");
    __doPostBack('btn', '');
}
```

4) in codebheind somemethod will be there which will does insert for you

Comment: The question is tagged asp.net-mvc, not web forms!